# Problem of Logic in Addressbook, should have no blank entries or same entry... Please Help

Tags: java, addressbook, conditional-operator

hope you can help me coding.

What i need to do:
1.) I should not allow user to have a blank entry.. I should prompt them like "No name inputted!"
2.) I should not allow user to input same entry..

I have no Idea how to code i, please help.

Here's my complete code:

public class AddressBook {

```
private AddressBookEntry entry[];
private int counter;
private String SName;
private int notfound=0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AddressBook a = new AddressBook();
    a.entry = new AddressBookEntry[100];
    int option = 0;
    while (option != 5) {
        String content = "Choose an Option\n\n"
                + "[1] Add an Entry\n"
                + "[2] Delete an Entry\n"
                + "[3] Update an Entry\n"
                + "[4] View all Entries\n"
                + "[5] View Specific Entry\n"
                + "[6] Exit";
        option = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(content));
        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                a.addEntry();
                break;
            case 2:
                a.deleteEntry();
                break;
            case 3:
                a.editEntry();
                break;
            case 4:
                a.viewAll();
                break;
            case 5:
                a.searchEntry();
                break;
            case 6:
                System.exit(1);
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Choice!");
        }
    }
}

public void addEntry() {
    entry[counter] = new AddressBookEntry();
    entry[counter].setName(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name: "));
    entry[counter].setAdd(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter add: "));
    entry[counter].setPhoneNo(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Phone No.: "));
    entry[counter].setEmail(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter E-mail: "));
    counter++;
}

public void viewAll() {
    String addText = "  NAME\tADDRESS\tPHONE NO.\tE-MAIL ADD\n\n";
    int nonNull = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
        if (entry[i] != null) {
            addText = addText + entry[i].getInfo() + "\n";
            nonNull++;
        }
        if (nonNull == counter) {
            break;
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JTextArea(addText));
}

public void searchEntry() {
    SName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name to find: ");
    searchMethod();
}

public void searchMethod() {
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        if (entry[i].getName().equals(SName)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, entry[i].getInfo2());
            notfound = 0;
            break;
        } else {
            notfound++;
        }
    }
    if (notfound != 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name Not Found!");
    }
}
public void editEntry() {
    int notfound = 0;
    SName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name to edit: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        if (entry[i].getName().equals(SName)) {
            entry[i] = new AddressBookEntry();
            entry[i].setName(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter new name: "));
            entry[i].setAdd(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter new add: "));
            entry[i].setPhoneNo(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter new Phone No.: "));
            entry[i].setEmail(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter new E-mail: "));
            notfound = 0;
            break;
        } else {
            notfound++;
        }
    }
    if (notfound != 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name Not Found!");
    }
}
public void deleteEntry() {
    SName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name to delete: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        if (entry[i].getName().equals(SName)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Found!");
            entry[i] = null;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

What happen to my code was it allows user to click "OK" even he doesn't enter any character yet.. and it also allows identical entry...

Hope you can help me... i need it very soon and yet i still have no Idea what to add in my code... please help thanks a lot..

Comment: If you are using JOptionPane anyway, you should look at `showOptionDialog` which allows you showing a list of buttons instead of an input line.

Comment: @Sir Paulo... good day... i am new at java and not familiar with the built-in functions... i'll try using this thanks :)

Comment: @Sir Paulo.. think this is what i really need... but when i try to apply it java says:"it cannot be applied to given types".. This is the what i do: entry[counter].setName(JOptionPane.showOptionDialog("Enter name: "));   Please Help thanks

Comment: @Sir Paulo... i've search about JOptionPane.showOptionDialog... but it doesnt asks for user input... what i need is... to check if the user inputed an entry or not.. and prompt him if he doesnt inputed any character yet... thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, showOptionDialog does not prompt for typing in input, but offers a list of options. I thought you wanted this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happen to my code was it allows user to click "OK" even he doesn't enter any character yet.. and it also allows identical entry...

The `showInputDialog` method lets the user input any string he wants, or also nothing. If you don't want this, you can either use a self-made dialog, patch the JOptionPane (using a subclass or such), or simply show the dialog again when it is not one of your given strings, like this:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(content);
try {
   option = Integer.parseInt(input);
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
   // the user typed nothing, or something that is not an integer
   // TODO: show error message
   // => go to next iteration of while loop.
   continue; 
}
// and now our switch ...
```

Comment: sorry... but can you help me code about knowing if the user typed nothing... i still have no idea... please help thanks

Comment: With my example above, the `parseInt` method throws an exception for "empty string", since this is not a valid integer. If you want to check on empty string, do a `if(input.equals("")) { ... }` test before this. (Or `input.isEmpty()` with Java 6 or later.)

Comment: O yes... but how about in my addEntry() Method... i want to detect if the user didn't input a name... sorry... i'm still a bit confused :(

Comment: It works the same way - put the result of the dialog to a variable and check its `isEmpty()` before calling `setName()`. Alternatively you could change your `setName` method to throw an exception when the name is empty (and would have to catch this exception).